# How to pass the array from a method to another method using interface

Tags: java, array, interface, encapsulamento

Quero criar um programa que use interfaces para criar uma classe vetor com nome e tamanho e tenha os métodos abaixo:

<>
+DefinirNomeTamanhoVetor
+PreencherVetorCriadoInformandoPosicaoValor
+OrdenarVetor
+ExibirVetor

> Não consigo passar o vetor de um método para usando a interface.

*Segue a classe do Vetor:*
package aula06Cencapsulamentotreino;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Vetor implements InterfaceControladora {

```
private int posicaovetor = 0;
private int tamanhovetor = 0;
private String nomevetor = "";


/**
 * @return the nome
 */
public String getNome() {
    return nomevetor;
}

/**
 * @param nome the nome to set
 */
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nomevetor = nome;
}

/**
 * @param posicao
 * @param tamanho
 */
public Vetor(int posicao, int tamanho) {
    super();
    this.posicaovetor = posicao;
    this.tamanhovetor = tamanho;
    this.nomevetor = nomevetor;
}

/**
 * @return the posicao
 */
private int getPosicao() {
    return posicaovetor;
}

/**
 * @param posicao the posicao to set
 */
private void setPosicao(int posicao) {
    this.posicaovetor = posicao;
}

/**
 * @return the tamanho
 */
private int getTamanho() {
    return tamanhovetor;
}

/**
 * @param tamanho the tamanho to set
 */
private void setTamanho(int tamanho) {
    this.tamanhovetor = tamanho;
}

@Override
public void metodoDefinicaoVetor(String nomevetor, int tamanhovetor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setNome(nomevetor);
    setTamanho(tamanhovetor);
    int v[] = new int[getTamanho()];
    Arrays.fill(v, 0);
    System.out.println("Nome do vetor = " + getNome());
    // Impressão dos valores dentro da posição do vetor.
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) { //
        System.out.printf(" " + v[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

@Override
public void metodoPreencimentoVetor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/*
 * @Override public void metodoOrdenacaoVetor() { // TODO Auto-generated method
 * stub int v[] = new int [getTamanho()]; Arrays.sort(v); }
 * 
 * @Override public void metodoBuscarValorVetor() { // TODO Auto-generated
 * method stub
 * 
 * }
 */
```

}

**Não consigo passar o vetor metodoDefinicaoVetor para o metodoPreencimentoVetor**

> > Como posso fazer isso com este programa?
> > Posso por links do git com meu programa aqui?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. Antes de a clarificar, leia um pouco sobre SOLID e Design Pattern talvez o ajude na reformulação.

Comment: Segue o Main para entende o que preciso: package aula06Cencapsulamentotreino;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;

public class ProgramaPrincipal {

 /**
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  // Instanciando e criando um vetor com nome e tamanho via construtor.
  Vetor vetor1 = new Vetor("vetorcriado01", 5);
  // Definindo o nome e tamanho do novo vetor
  vetor1.metodoDefinicaoVetor("vetorcriado02", 3);
  vetor1.metodoPreencimentoVetor();
//vetor1.metodoOrdenacaoVetor();

 }
}

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se precisa usar interface, basta adicionar a interface como parâmetro do seu método. Todas os objetos das classes que implementarem a sua interface poderão ser passadas como parâmetro.
Uma outra forma é declarar o seu "v[]" como uma váriavel fora do método metodoDefinicaoVetor e acessar ela diretamente de dentro do metodoPreencimentoVetor.

```
    @Override
public void metodoDefinicaoVetor(String nomevetor, int tamanhovetor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setNome(nomevetor);
    setTamanho(tamanhovetor);
    v[] = new int[getTamanho()]; // declara o "int v[]" fora desse método. Aqui faz somente a inicilização dele.
    Arrays.fill(v, 0);
    System.out.println("Nome do vetor = " + getNome());
    // Impressão dos valores dentro da posição do vetor.
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) { //
        System.out.printf(" " + v[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

@Override
public void metodoPreencimentoVetor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: Melhorei a pergunta e postei o programa inteiro para facilitar... a ideia é usar o vetor criado no método de preenchimento para operações, busca e ordenação. [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/473266/como-associar-um-vetor-%c3%a1-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-para-usar-entre-m%c3%a9todos]